# Scaling php functions on a huge php page to easier customize functions for different customers

Tags: php

I didn't really know how to create a good question for my "problem", but at least I hope it covers the essence of what I'm after.

The specific project I am working on right now is to a great extent scaled and values from a database sets most of the properties and displayed elements on the page for each customer.

But, on some points I don't know of any good, simple methods of scaling as in for instance:

When a customers logs in, it is presented with a form for creation of an entry. Which input fields are displayed are based on what is set in the DB. So far, so good. But, for most customers there is a field called "code" which is usually a 4-digit INT. Furhtermore, some customers are allowed to fill in this code manually, but for others it's being automatically generated after submission based on given conditions.

My scaling problem occurs in the last event. Because there are two different ways of that input field to be displayed (it's either displayed as an active input, or a disabled input). I solved this adding a column to my customers table in the DB which is either enabled or disabled and the input field is displayed correspondingly.

And this is the part which has really put my little gray ones to work: If the field is disabled and the code is automatically genereated, some customers may have a given number of entries with code values 1,2,3,4 for their respective entries. For some customers, if the entry with the number "2" is deleted that number can be reused upon creation of a new entry, but for others, that number is forever taken and the only possible assignable number to a new entry is (in this instance) "5". Worth to note that the code is ALWAYS in series from low to high, never random.

As far as my knowledge goes this is the only solution I have come up with:

1. Add a field to the database and have three conditions: 1 for normal active field, 2 for disabled field with reusable numbers and 3 for disabled field with non-reusable numbers (always increments +1 from the highest value in the DB).
2. Create respective functions to call if the user has either of the three options.

The three functions would then be:

1. echo out the normal, active field and store the value entered
2. echo out the disabled field, check the numbers present in the db and give the entry the lowest possible code value that isn't present (e.g. if there are 3 entries with values 1,3,4 - give the new entry the value of 2)
3. echo out the disabled field, check the highest number (which would be the last entry) and give the new entry the code of the highest number +1

Would this be a good way to go about this? Or could it be done more effectively? I know the semantics of using 1, 2 or 3 as conditions isn't good, but it's just for illustration in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you're making things Unnecessarily hard...  I have a couple other options:

1. You let the auto-generation of the number and enable/disable of the field occur as you currently do.  As far as being more restrictive for certain clients who can only re-use or only enter certain numbers into the field, you let them enter anything they want at the form time, and then in your post-submission script, decide if they need to be sent back to the form to re-enter something...  Even better, use some jQuery/JS to check the fields live for them as well.
2. Other option may be to use drop down menus `<select>`.  You could pre-generate allowed characters in this method before displaying the form, based on your conditions.

Comment: Your first suggestion is not an option for function 2+3 as it would only be confusing for the customer to have to manually input something just to realize it's invalid and having to try again. It's better that those remain auto-generated.

Your second suggestion though might be more useful. On first login, I could present them with two drop downs, one to choose how many digits the code should consist of, and the second whether or not they will use unique or non-unique numbers. Atleast then I don't have to set this in the DB manually.